# Watermark does not print correctly

Tags: pdf, printing, itext

I'm using iTextSharp to add a watermark to existing PDF files. When viewing these files on screen, the watermark and PDF appears correctly. However, when printing on certain printers (2 out of 3 that have been tested by the client), the watermark seems to interfere with the content that is above it causing it to appear malformed when printed.

The PDF's are of CAD drawings (i.e. electrical circuit drawings etc.)

The code being used to apply the watermark is below. The `PdfContentByte` is retrieved by a call to `GetOverContent` from the class `PdfStamper`

```
private void AddWaterMark(PdfContentByte dc, string text, BaseFont font, float fontSize, float angle, BaseColor color, Rectangle realPageSize, Rectangle rect = null)
{
    var gstate = new PdfGState { FillOpacity = 0.1f, StrokeOpacity = 0.3f };
    dc.SaveState();
    dc.SetGState(gstate);
    dc.SetColorFill(color);

    dc.BeginText();
    dc.SetFontAndSize(font, fontSize);
    var ps = rect ?? realPageSize; /*dc.PdfDocument.PageSize is not always correct*/
    var x = (ps.Right + ps.Left) / 2;
    var y = (ps.Bottom + ps.Top) / 2;
    dc.ShowTextAligned(Element.ALIGN_CENTER, text, x, y, angle);
    dc.EndText();
    dc.RestoreState();
}
```

---

Here is an example of what it looks like on screen:

[image]

---

Here is what it looks like when printed on some of the printers:
[image]

---

Can anyone give me any idea on why certain printers will not print the PDF correctly and if I can change the way I apply the watermarks to avoid this issue?

Comment: If I understand you well, the PDF is printed correctly on 1 out of 3 printers? What are the printers you have tested? Brand + model. Also, could you share the PDF file?

Comment: Can you be more specific about word such as "interfere" and "malformed"? A scan of a printed page might help.

Comment: @ChrisHaas, i've added some examples

Comment: Thanks link64, that really helps to see it. Just a guess, try drawing the text with a stroke only, no fill. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7837029/231316) should get you the basic commands, just use `PdfContentByte.TEXT_RENDER_MODE_STROKE`

Comment: *Can anyone give me any idea on why certain printers will not print the PDF correctly* - most likely those printers do not support pdf fully (problems with transparency or different colour spaces or something like that) or the original pdf had issues even before watermarking. Or were they pdf/x?